# GDI window paints black on all paints except the first

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

So I'm working on an emulator, and got stuck on trying to paint a GDI window. Basically I have this code:

```
switch(uMsg)
{
    case WM_SIZE:
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
        HDC const PaintDC = BeginPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
        RECT ClientRect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &ClientRect);
        int const WindowWidth = ClientRect.right - ClientRect.left;
        int const WindowHeight = ClientRect.bottom - ClientRect.top;
        StretchDIBits(PaintDC,
                      0, 0,
                      WindowWidth,
                      WindowHeight,
                      0, 0,
                      DecodedScreenMemory.Info.bmiHeader.biWidth,
                      DecodedScreenMemory.Info.bmiHeader.biHeight,
                      DecodedScreenMemory.Memory,
                      &DecodedScreenMemory.Info,
                      DIB_RGB_COLORS,
                      SRCCOPY);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &Ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        Running = false;
        Result = 0;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        Result = DefWindowProc(hwnd,
                               uMsg,
                               wParam,
                               lParam);
    }
}
```

In another place of the program I have a piece of code that, for now, fills an 8 pixels wide border with white leaving the rest black. So, from what I understand, I have the window buffer, then I call StretchDIBits with appropriate parameters, then at every frame I call UpdateWindow and it should render the buffer on screen. Why does it turn black instead?

Comment: You don't return a value from your window procedure. Why don't you show a MCVE?

Comment: What is *DecodedScreenMemory*?  Is it a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: UpdateWindow does nothing if the window has not been invalidated.

Comment: DecodedScreenMemory is a structure that contains a BITMAPINFO and the rendering buffer. @RawN

Comment: How do I invalidate a window? @RaymondChen

Comment: InvalidateRect or RedrawWindow.

Comment: @JonathanPotter not working, tried both

Comment: *"not working"* is not an error description. If you need help, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Those `HDC const` and `int const` variables look rather weird to me. Why `const`? Did you check the values they get? And it's quite reasonable to ask, is the source bitmap really larger than 1x1 pixel?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou: Those variables are `const`, because they never change throughout their lifetimes. There's nothing weird here. (It is weird, that I don't see `const` applied more often, really.)